# Turn java XML SAX Parser to web app Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, sax

I've got a java SAX Parser for XML (we set the date, make URL reqest for this date and parse XML file). Now I need to turn this code to web app in Tomcat. I've imported all nessessary libraries, created artefacts, but don't know how to change code itself.\

Here is initial code

**Handler:**

```
public class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

boolean bName = false;
boolean bValue = false;
String result=" ";

@Override
public void startElement(String uri,
                         String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Valute")) {
        String CharCode = attributes.getValue("CharCode");
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
        bName = true;
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Value")) {
        bValue = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri,
                       String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Valute")) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (bName) {
        result=(new String(ch, start, length)+" ");
        bName = false;
    } else if (bValue) {
        result=result+(new String(ch, start, length));
        bValue = false;

        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
}
```

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        //Set the date dd.mm.yyyy

        String date="12.08.2020";

        String link ="http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=";
       URL url =new URL(link);

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            UserHandler userHandler = new UserHandler();
            saxParser.parse(String.valueOf(url+date), userHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The entry point into your logic will no longer be a static `main` method, but rather a servlet (a separate class) which will invoke your parser based on a HTTP request. Have you created that servlet? If this is a question about how to create servlets, then that is too broad for this site. Otherwise, can you clarify your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to change Main for servlet. I've created a servlet and tried to adapt my main by it. But there are errors like: Error during artifact deployment, Error starting child, Invalid <url-pattern>

Comment: It sounds as if maybe your basic servlet is broken (_"error during artifact deployment"_). My recommendation: Start by setting up the simplest, most basic "hello world" servlet - one that works when deployed to Tomcat, and which can respond to a URL request from a browser. There are lots of online guides for that. Once that is working, then you can try adding your parser classes. But without any _specific_ problem details in your question, no-one will be able to help you.